# Regex in xCode: any number of any whitespace characters including "end of line"?

Tags: regex, xcode, whitespace, combinations, end-of-line

I my case I have the following text:

```
- (NSUInteger) launcherView:(HMLauncherView *)launcherView 
        numberOfIconsInPage:(NSUInteger)page;
```

And I want to find all the matches for this method. The regexp should look like something like this:

```
launcherView:<any number of characters><any number of whitespaces or "ends of line">numberOfIconsInPage:
```

I know `<any number of characters>` means `(.+)` and `<whitespace>` means `\s` but how to write the whole expression? My main problem - I can't make it searching for any combination of whitespaces because it differs whitespace characters and "end of line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex could be this one:

```
/launcherView:.+(\s*|\s*$)numberOfIconsInPage:/
```

In particular, the `".+"` matches any character, the `(\s*|\s*$)` matches either only whitespaces until the `"numberOfIconsInPage"` or any number of whitespaces until the end of line.

Comment: everything is ok, but the slashes at the beginning and at the end are extra